# Update on a spoon transformation gives 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint'

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, etl, kettle

I am trying to create a transformation using Kettle that can read a table from my database and then connect to a remote postgresql database, insert new rows into the remote database (or update if value changed, or not do anything if the remote table has the same data as my table). It works fine on inserting but when it tries to update a row, I get the following error:

```
Insert / Update.0 - ERROR (version 5.2.0.0, build 1 from 2014-09-30_19-48-28 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleStepException: 
2014/10/15 16:52:54 - Insert / Update.0 - Error in step, asking everyone to stop because of:
2014/10/15 16:52:54 - Insert / Update.0 - Error inserting/updating row
2014/10/15 16:52:54 - Insert / Update.0 - ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_pentaho_pkey"
2014/10/15 16:52:54 - Insert / Update.0 -   Detail: Key (id)=(3) already exists.
```

I am confused as to why its trying to insert because id is a primary key, so if that id exists, it should just update it, instead of trying to insert it. How can I go around this? Am I doing something wrong in Insert/Update step settings?

This is my Insert/Update step settings on spoon's interface:

[image]

My database table contents:

```
 id |    name    | age
----+------------+-----
  1 | ioqw       |  50
  2 | 12132      |  32
  4 | test_data1 |  24
  5 | test_data1 |  24
  6 | hello      |  24
  3 | hello3     |  50
(6 rows)
```

Remote database table contents:

```
 id |    name    | age
----+------------+-----
  1 | ioqw       |  50
  2 | 12132      |  32
  3 | test_data  |  14
  4 | test_data1 |  24
  5 | test_data1 |  24
(5 rows)
```

I was trying to update remote table's row with id=3.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Yup, it did. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from the error message the primary key of the target table is only on the `id` column. However, in your update component you ask Spoon to use a combined key of columns `id`, `age` and `name` to determine if an entry exists (see entries below *Key(s) to look up the values*). You will have to remove columns `name` and `age` from this list.